# Como mostrar uma imagem na janela de informações do marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Ao clicar em um `marker` criado com a API do Google Maps, é possível adicionar uma janela de informações, que é o que o código abaixo faz:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent("image.png");
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
```

Como é reproduzido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria de em vez de mostrar no balão o texto da imagem, `image.png` , gostaria de visualizar a imagem de fato. Como mostrar uma imagem na janela de informações do marker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a própria [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows?hl=pt-br) do google, tu pode simplesmente colocar a tag da imagem em uma string e passa-la para o `content` da `infowindow`.

ex:

```
var contentString = '<img src="image.png">';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });
```

Segue um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vd7x0kn1/) disponibilizado na documentação de como fazer isso.